# How to split a string by a collection of chars?

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I have a string that contains substrings, which are separated by a set of chars like `,`, `.`, `-`, `;` and probably other. I need to split that string into as many substrings there are. And I need to understand how that splitting with that for loop works so I can add the other chars when needed.

**Example:**

```
set string=aaa,bbb.ccc-ddd;eee
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-.," %%a in ("%string%") do ( echo %%a, %%b )
```

I need to get to the result of 5 substrings in this example: **aaa**, **bbb**, **ccc**, **ddd**, **eee**. In that for loop I'd like to work with each of these substrings, like in a normal programming language. But this is killing me.

I get like **aaa**, **bbb.ccc-ddd;eee**. Only 2 substrings. What a I doing wrong? Also there might be a 1000 substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR /F` splits a line into multiple tokens (up to 31), but these tokens have to be defined.

```
for /f "tokens=1-31 delims=-.," %%a in ("%string%") do ( echo %%a, %%b, %%c %%d, %%e, %%f, ... )
```

But thats useless in your case with up to 100 tokens.

But you can force `FOR /F` to suppose it's getting multiple lines, and for each line the tokenization starts again.

```
(set \n=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%L in ("!\n!") do (
    set "multiLine=!string:-=%%~L!"
    set "multiLine=!multiLine:;=%%~L!"
    set "multiLine=!multiLine:,=%%~L!"
    set "multiLine=!multiLine:.=%%~L!"
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("!multiLine!") do ( 
    echo # %%a
)
```

First, it replaces all of your characters `-,;.` to a newline `\n`.
The `FOR /F` works on a *per line* basis, so you get in `%%a` one part in each loop

Comment: You mean there is no other alternative for splitting strings?

Comment: @Bitterblue There are some. But they use a bit more advanced technics